# C++ How to delete a specific object in a vector?

Tags: c++, loops, vector

I'm trying to figure out how to delete a specific object in a vector. I'm searching the vector based on a string named id. Hoping someone can help me fill in the blanks! Thanks! Is the way i'm erasing valid??

my vector is like this:

```
 vector<member*> memb;
```

and this is what i have so far:

```
for (int i = 0; i < memb.size(); i++)
{
    if( std::find(memb.begin(),memb.end(), id) != memb.end() ) {
        myvector.erase (memb.begin(),memb.begin()=id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Get rid of your loop.  `std::find()` (and `std::find_if()`) does the necessary looping for you.

`std::find()` (and `std::find_if()`) returns an iterator to the element if found, or the specified `last` iterator if not found.  If the element is found, pass the returned iterator to the vector's `erase()` method to remove the element.

Since you are storing pointers in your vector, you cannot use `std::find()` to search by a `std::string` value.  You need to use `std::find_if()` instead.

Try this:

```
struct isID
{
    const std::string &m_id;

    isID(const std::string &id) : m_id(id) {}

    bool operator()(const member *m) const
    {
        return (m->id == m_id);
    }
};
```

```
std::string id = ...;

std::vector<member*>::iterator iter = std::find_if(memb.begin(), memb.end(), isID(id));
if (iter != memb.end())
{
    // since you are storing pointers in the vector, you
    // need to free the object being pointed at, if noone
    // else owns it...

    //delete *iter;
    memb.erase(iter);
}
```

Or, if you are using C++11 or later:

```
std::string id = ...;

auto iter = std::find_if(memb.begin(), memb.end(),
                [id](const member* m) { return (m->id == id); } );
if (iter != memb.end())
{
    // since you are storing pointers in the vector, you
    // need to free the object being pointed at, if noone
    // else owns it...

    //delete *iter;
    memb.erase(iter);
}
```

In the latter case, if the vector is intended to own the objects, you can store `std::unique_ptr` objects in the vector to automatically free the `member` objects for you:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<member>> memb;

...

std::unique_ptr<member> m(new member); 
// or: std::unique_ptr<member> m = std::make_unique_ptr<member>(); 
memb.push_back(std::move(m));

// or: memb.push_back(std::unique_ptr<member>(new member)); 
// or: memb.push_back(std::make_unique<member>()); 
// or: memb.emplace_back(new member); 

...

if (iter != memb.end())
{
    // std::unique_ptr will free the object automatically
    // when the std::unique_ptr itself is destroyed...

    memb.erase(iter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    vector<member *>::iterator iter;
    for (iter=memb.begin(); iter!=memb.end();) {
        if ((*iter)->id == id) {
            delete (*iter);
            iter = memb.erase(iter);
        } else {
            iter++;
       }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.